# $A^3 = I$. Find the possible Jordan Forms???

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

If $A^3 = I$, then I want to find the possible Jordan forms of the matrix.  Since the minimal polynomial has degree at most three, each block is at most 3, and the eigenvalues are third roots of unity.

Is that the answer, or are there some other components I am missing?

Comment: Since $X^n-1$ has no repeated roots, $m_A$ has no repeated roots. Since it seems you're working on $\Bbb C$, the minimal polynomials factors linearly and you have a diagonalizable matrix.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433806/a-be-a-complex-3-times-3-matrix-such-that-a3-i

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're a little off there.  Note that $A^3 = I$, which means that $A^3 - I = 0$, which means that the minimal polynomial $q_A(t)$ of $A$ divides
$$
t^3 - 1= (t-1)(t-\omega)(t-\omega^2)
$$
where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ is a root of unity.  Note that the maximal degree of any factor of the minimal polynomial is $1$, which means that the maximum length Jordan block for any given eigenvalue is $1$.

Comment: PS: is this Horn and Johnson?

Comment: Yes it's a problem from their 2013 edition.  I just don't see how it's a reasonable question considering generalized eigenvectors and minimal polynomials don't pop up until a later section. Is there some other way to arrive at the answer using just the uniqueness and existence of Jordan form? Maybe something around the geometric and algebraic multiplicity of each eigenvalue?

Comment: Also please note that it doesn't say anywhere that $A \neq I$ or $A^2 \neq I$, so that may change things right?

Comment: Well, that bit with the minimal polynomial tells you everything you need to know: the Jordan form of $A$ has to be diagonal, with some combination of $1$s, $\omega$s, and $\omega^2$s on the diagonal.  You could have $A = I$, which would happen if all diagonal entries are $1$. You are correct in noting that $A^2 = I$ is not disallowed, but given that $A^3 = I$, we would have $A^2 = A^3 = I$ and thus $A = I$.

Answer (score 3):

The minimal polynomial doesn't have repeated roots.  Therefore the matrix is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work only with real matrices, then you can separate out the real and imaginary part to get
$$
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cr 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

You can always do a similarity transforms to get other solutions!